# Node server running but localhost "still loading "

Tags: node.js

I do have a NodeJs application, and until now it was working, I just shouted down my laptop. When I run " npm start " server is starting but, the localhost page is not loading or is loading but every request I make it's not working. I can't get any pages or submit forms, I mean just on loading and sometimes I get an " Establishing connection... " or " Waiting for localhost " , or the form's buttons don't work at all.

```
app.use(feedRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);

app.use(errorController.get404);

mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI)
  .then(result => {
  app.listen(80);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

This is a part of my app.js where I did the server creation, it runs, but it's not loading at all. I think it's not connecting to the database but the Cluster is ON and I can access it from Compass app

I CHANGED THE BROWSER AND WORKED WELL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your page is being loaded from a cache. Always remember to clear your browser's cache when you start a fresh instance of your server or frontend application. That is `Ctrl+Shift+R` if you are using Chrome or FireFox or set up a browser profile that specifically disables caching.

Answer (score 0):

Change your port to another number and try it again.